# How do I change the texture of a particular Geom in a GeomNode?

Tags: python, panda3d

Some context: I'm dynamically generating some tile-based graphics by creating a Geom for each tile (containing only a couple of tris), then combining all Geoms into a single GeomNode for the whole map.

According to the [panda3d docs](https://www.panda3d.org/manual/index.php/GeomNode), one of the uses of a GeomNode is to be able to change the texture for individual Geoms. However, it doesn't explain how to do this.

Calling `set_texture` on the Geom itself doesn't work (presumably since the RenderState is in the GeomNode, not the Geom). I can get the RenderState corresponding to the nth Geom with `geom_node.get_geom_state(n)`, and set it again with `geom_node.set_geom_state(n, state)`, but I don't know how to change the RenderState so that it applies a texture, and from the API reference it looks very complicated.

How do I change the texture on an individual Geom in a GeomNode (and if the answer is "put each Geom in its own GeomNode", then is there ever a reason to have more than one Geom per GeomNode)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out if you read the documentation a little more closely, it [says](https://www.panda3d.org/reference/1.7.2/python/panda3d.core.RenderState.php#_details):

> You should not attempt to create or modify a RenderState object directly. Instead, call one of the make() functions to create one for you. And instead of modifying a RenderState object, create a new one.

So to update the texture on Geom `n`, given some texture `texture` and a GeomNode `node`, you need to do something like this:

```
attrib = TextureAttrib.make(texture)
state = RenderState.make(attrib)
node.set_geom_state(n, state)
```